# Performing WS-Discovery from within WinRT

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-runtime, ws-discovery

I'd like to use WS-Discovery from within a WinRT application I'm developing, but this doesn't appear to be available. Whilst it's available within the .Net Frameworks's WCF 4.0, they appear to have ommitted it from WinRT.

Since it's WinRT, I cannot reference System.ServiceModel.Discovery.

Can anyone recommend an alternative? I could probably implement a basic version of this standard myself, but would like to avoid the work if I can. It might make a nice OSS project.

Comment: There is a bunch of Win32 calls related to Web Services that are still supported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205759.aspx). I am not sure of discovery specifically.

Comment: I don't think it is in there. Is there something in JQuery you can use? Maybe switch to a JavaScript project and try that?

Comment: I don't think the Win32 calls nor jQuery include anything related to WS-Discovery. Are there any other technologies that can be used for dynamic service discovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WS-Discovery isn't supported by the WinRT API.

The API does support UDP Multicasting, so I can use that to perform peer discovery.

Comment: Did you find the way for WS-Discovery using WInRT. PLz help me on that

Comment: No, sorry, that portion of the protocol just isn't available in WinRT at this time. Not to my knowledge anyway.

Comment: Tell you the API? I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry its typo ...Tell me the WinRT api or code snippets which does UDP Multicasting